# Pass in passwords in Lambda event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, passwords

Is it insecure to send a password into a Lambda using the Event?

I have one Lambda calling another, and it would be convenient to not look up the password in Secrets Manager a second time.

Comment: Seems like a questionable security practice. I would not want to have to defend this in an application security review or, worse, a root cause analysis following a breach.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how valuable the password is, and whether or not it's time-bound.  If it's a relatively static password, then you can look it up in both Lambda functions during static initialization so that you only retrieve it once for each Lambda container.  Putting the password in the event means that it might get logged somewhere.  How impactful would someone seeing the password in CloudWatch be?

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. It does bring up another question for me, though. I don't see how to handle errors in a static initialization block. In the Lambda handler, if there is an error pulling the passwords I want to return statusCode 500, but outside a function there is no way to return  to the calling Lambda, is there?

Comment: If static initialization fails, Lambda will return a 5xx error to the caller, and the details of the failure should be logged in CloudWatch (assuming you have CloudWatch logging enabled).  It'd also be good to catch exceptions during static initialization and send some details to CloudWatch log to help you understand why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Uff :D

okay, I will just write down how I do things.

1. Lambda do not call lambda. We use decoupled architecture using SQS, SNS or similar.
2. Lambda has password it needs in environment variables, that will be initialized by deployment in the pipeline. This way lambda does not have to ask parameter store, it has all the passwords as soon as it is deployed.

Do with that information what ever you want :) ! gl !

Comment: Please make the answer more professional. Remove all those uff and other not needed things which are not relevant to the issue.